# Logical Groups in Team System

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We use TFS2010 and we have a team of developers and a team of testers. Currently, we have a team query that display all the work items that were created by the development team and a different team query that displays all the work items that were created by the test team. These lists are very explicit in including the usernames e.g.:

```
And/Or    Field         Operator    Value
          Team Project  =           @Project
And       Created By    =           John
And       Created By    =           Kane
And       Created By    =           Sam
And       Created By    =           Matt
And       Created By    =           Ben
```

Is there a way to create a group in TFS e.g. Development Team or Testing Team so that you only have to specify the group name and not list every user individually?

E.g.:

```
And/Or    Field         Operator    Value
          Team Project  =           @Project
And       Created By    =           Testing Team
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the users are in different Groups, this should be quite straightforward with operator `In Group`:
[image]